# In the envelope theorem, why can I write my inputs $x$ and $y$ as a function of $\xi$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

This is a question about the envelope theorem.  Suppose I have a maximization problem

$$\max_{x,y} f(x,y,\xi)$$
such that
$$g(x,y,\xi) \leq c$$
where $x$ and $y$ are control variables and $\xi$ is a given parameter which affects $f$ and/or $g$, but over which we do not maximize.

We write the Lagrangian 
$$L(x,y,\xi) = f(x,y,\xi) - \lambda (g(x,y,\xi) - c)$$
for which the two first order conditions are given by

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(x,y,\xi)}{\partial x}  -\lambda \frac{\partial g(x,y,\xi)}{\partial x} =0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f(x,y,\xi)}{\partial y}  -\lambda \frac{\partial g(x,y,\xi)}{\partial y}=0 $$

The next step in the several sets or notes I have seen say I need to solve this problem say I need to write a function

$$F(\xi) = f(x(\xi),y(\xi),\xi)$$
and take the total derivative.

Let me know if anything isn't clear and I will fix it.

**My Question:**

Why can I write $x$ and $y$ as functions of $\xi$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^*(\xi)$, $y^*(\xi)$ be the solution of the optimization problem for a given value of the parameter $\xi$.

Then $f\left(x^*(\xi), y^*(\xi), \xi\right)$ is the value of the maximum of $f$, at a fixed value of the parameter $\xi$.

The envelope theorem tells you how this value changes when you change the parameter, i.e. how the maximum of the function moves when you vary $\xi$.

Namely, it tells you that in order to find the derivative of this "maximum" wrt. $\xi$ at $\xi_0$, you just have to take the partial derivative of the lagrangian wrt. $\xi$ and evaluate it at the points $x^*(\xi)$, $y^*(\xi)$ that maximize $f$ when $\xi = \xi_0$.

Formally

$$
\frac{\partial f\left(x^*(\xi), y^*(\xi), \xi\right)}{\partial \xi}|_{\xi_0} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \xi}|_{x^*(\xi_0), y^*(\xi_0)}
$$